# How to Highlight unread WordPress posts?

Tags: php, cookies

I need to show a new post marker for unread posts, placed after its date as is shown in the image below:

[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [update_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and [get_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta), where you can store and retrieve a value related to a key and a user, like `'read_post_' . $post_id` for example.

Inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), when you're going to print the article, you can add a condition: if the user has the user meta value `'read_post_' . $post_id` as false or not set, you could print that blue circle.

```
if(get_user_meta($user_id, 'read_post_' . $post_id, true) != ""){
 // show the notification
}
```

And when you print the inside of the article you can update that value, so it will be set as true:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'read_post_' . $post_id, true );
```

Comment: Thanks @dgarceran! It seems that is working only for loogged-in users? Because I need it to work for visitors. However, It make sense but is not clear to me how the `'read_post_'` will work.

Comment: `'read_post_' . $post_id` is the name (key) of the value you're setting in the database related to that user. The `$post_id` will be the ID of the post that you're showing right now, so it makes the key unique for that post and not available for another one.

Comment: And if you want to work with guests and not registered users, try to look at [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (Local Storage) that would make you able to save on the client side some information (with javascript) that you can send to the server side with an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You may please follow this tutorial http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-highlight-new-posts-for-returning-visitors-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me.